# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0 error while initializing Mat in android

Tags: android, opencv, mat

I am trying to initialize Mat and this is my code

```
    Mat imgRgba = new Mat();
    final Bitmap bitmap =
    Bitmap.createBitmap(imgRgba.width(), imgRgba.height(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Utils.matToBitmap(imgRgba, bitmap);
```

I have tried this too

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(imgRgba.cols(), imgRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

but when I am going to run my app I am getting crash and exception is this

```
    Stack trace:  
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:969)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:948)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:915)
    at com.jmr.agency.banking.ui.facerecognition.FRAddPersonPreviewActivity.onCameraFrame(FRAddPersonPreviewActivity.java:156)
```

Comment: Stack trace clearly mentioned the problem: *width and height must be > 0*

Comment: Mat is Matrix in OpenCV, exactly for what purpose you are using Mat and Bitmap together?

Answer (score 0):

Try either [mat.create(int rows, int cols, int type)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a55ced2c8d844d683ea9a725c60037ad0) or some [other constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#af1d014cecd1510cdf580bf2ed7e5aafc) for Mat object, as currently it does not have a size.

Comment: Can You Initialize this Mat because I have tried all way?

Comment: and one more thing , am I getting this exception because Mat is not initialized properly?

Comment: Yes. You can open any of the links I added in my comment, and there you'll have the full explanation of 1.) how to call mat.create() + example of calling it; and 2.) how to use different constructors

Answer (score 0):

You did new instance Mat for size. But it has no size.If you have `bitmap` or `Mat` data you can use your code like this:

```
 private Bitmap getBitmap(Mat imgRgb){
    final Bitmap bitmap =
    Bitmap.createBitmap(imgRgba.width(), imgRgba.height(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(imgRgba, bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Now you can call this method with your existing `Mat` data for convert your `Mat` data to `bitmap`.

Or you can convert your `Bitmap` to `Mat`:

```
private Bitmap getMat(Bitmap bitmap){
        Mat mat = new Mat();
        mat = Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap,mat);
        return mat;
}
```

Hope you understand.